# Chrome shows unique result for some different ajax requests

Tags: ajax, google-chrome

I have placed following code into a page

```
function load_tip(obj)
{
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  else xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
      obj.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open('GET','[url]',true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
var adverts = document.getElementsByClassName('advert');
for (var i = 0; i < adverts.length; ++i) {
  load_tip(adverts[i]);
}
```

there is some divs with class name `advert` in the page and [url] points to another webpage that products random advertise. In Firefox different texts shows in the divs but in Chrome one text is loaded into all the divs.

Does chrome sends only one request and shows result for each request that I writes? How could I correct this behavior for Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
I replaced GET with POST and add some random information into url (as unused parameter). Chrome doesn't cache this request anymore